# Upload a file using django model issue

Tags: jquery, python, django

```
file_name = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.PATH, verbose_name=_('Upload_Path'), \
                                null=True, blank=True, help_text=' .zip file only')
```

When I rendring this field using forms it Shows me  button `<input type="file" name="file" id="id_file">` and beside this button `No file chosen` text come.

When I upload any document suppose `foo.zip` The `No file chosen` remains there and `foo.zip` just overwrite it. Ideally `No file chosen` should be removed. What may be the reason?

If jquery can help me to solve this problem then it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon the browser you are using. Jquery has nothing to do with it.. Django forms just create a file field. Browser displays the file open dialog and added file in their own style. This has nothing to do with your code.